# ios setting alpha to all objects on view

Tags: ios

In iOS 4.0.2, I would like to set the alpha to 0.00 for each object on the view that I has a tag of 100.

```
  (id object in [self.view subviews])
     {   
     if ([object tag]  == 100)      
         {

          //what goes here ...

         }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.view viewWithTag:100].alpha = 0.0;
```

There's no need to set the alpha of all views. The alpha applies cumulatively to all subviews. So the whole tree starting at that view will become invisible.

Makes more sense to do this usually, rather than set the alpha to 0:

```
[self.view viewWithTag:100].hidden = YES;
```

Comment: [self.view viewWithTag:100].alpha = 0.0; and [self.view viewWithTag:100].hidden = YES; compiled but did not hide the objects. I will look into why later when I have more time, my gut is telling me the problem is in referencing "that" view. Thank You.

Comment: Use the debugger and see what the return value of viewWithTag is (assign it to a temporary local variable to make it easier). Possibly it's nil (the code won't crash, but won't do anything either). Then my guess is either your view doesn't really have tag 100, or it's not a subview (direct or indirect) of self.view. Possibly it's a different view. If so then you are assigning the tag 100 to another view (possibly both views).